# SQL query that summarizes each group

Tags: sql

I need help with this. I need to summarize each group of tests. The result should look like this:

```
name_of_the_group  |  all_test_cases  |  passed_test_cases  |  total_value
numerical stability          4                    4                 80
memory usage                 3                    2                 20
corner cases                 0                    0                  0
performance                  2                    0                  0
```

columns:

1. name_of_the_group (all groups need to be displayed even if there are no corresponding tests)
2. all_test_cases (number of tests in the group)
3. passed_test_cases (number of test cases with the status OK)
4. total_value (total value of passed tests in this group)

Here is the fiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e96109

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple conditional aggregation:

```
select
  t.name,
  count(*) as total,
  sum(case when c.status = 'OK' then 1 else 0 end) as passed,
  sum(case when c.status = 'OK' then test_value end) as score
from
test_groups t
left join test_cases c
 on t.name = c.group_name
 group by t.name
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e96109/12)

Comment: Hi @Andrew your query has 'corner cases' as 1 under the test_cases, however,  if you manually check the test_cases, you will see there was no test ran for that group.

Answer (score 4):

Below SQL query provide a solution to all test cases

1. When there is a name entry in table test_groups but missing in test_cases.
2. Order by test_value desc first and then by name lexicographically increasing
   order.

`SELECT CASE
           WHEN g.name = c.group_name THEN c.group_name
           ELSE g.name
       END AS name,
       count(c.group_name) AS all_test_cases,
       count(CASE
                 WHEN c.status = 'OK' THEN 1
             END) AS all_test_cases,
       sum(CASE
               WHEN c.status = 'OK' THEN g.test_value
               ELSE 0
           END) AS total_value
FROM test_groups g
LEFT JOIN test_cases c ON g.name = c.group_name
GROUP BY CASE
             WHEN g.name = c.group_name THEN c.group_name
             ELSE g.name
         END
ORDER BY total_value DESC,
         CASE
             WHEN g.name = c.group_name THEN c.group_name
             ELSE g.name
         END`

Answer (score 1):

```
with all_test_cases as (select name, count(id) as cnt from (
 select a.name, a.test_value, b.id, b.status from test_groups a
 left  join test_cases b on a.name = b.group_name) total_test
 group by name), 
 passed_test_cases as (
 select name, count(name) as cnt from (
 select a.name, a.test_value, b.id, b.status from test_groups a
 join test_cases b on a.name = b.group_name
 and b.status = 'OK') OK_test
 group by name)


 select tg.name, atc.cnt as all_test_cases , coalesce(ptc.cnt, 0) as passed_test_cases, coalesce(ptc.cnt * tg.test_value, 0) as total_value
 from test_groups tg
 left join all_test_cases atc on tg.name = atc.name
 left join passed_test_cases ptc on tg.name = ptc.name
 order by total_value desc, name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select t.name,
sum(case when c.status = 'OK' or c.status = 'ERROR'  then 1 else 0 end) as all_test_cases,
sum(case when c.status = 'OK' then 1 else 0 end) as passed_test_cases,
sum(case when c.status = 'OK' then 1 else 0 end) * t.test_value as total_value
from
test_groups t
left join test_cases c
on t.name = c.group_name
group by t.name,t.test_value
order by ,t.total_value,t.name
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH A AS (SELECT group_name AS name, COUNT(status) AS all_test_cases,
                  SUM(CASE
                          WHEN status = 'OK' THEN 1
                          ELSE 0
                      END) AS passed_test_cases
           FROM test_cases
           GROUP BY group_name)

SELECT g.name, IFNULL(c.all_test_cases,0), 
       IFNULL(c.passed_test_cases,0), 
       IFNULL(g.test_value*c.passed_test_cases,0) AS total_value
FROM test_groups AS g
LEFT JOIN A AS c
ON g.name = c.name
GROUP BY g.name
ORDER BY total_value DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Name Name_Of_The_Group ,Count(Status) All_Test_Cases,
Sum(Case When Status = 'OK' Then 1 Else 0 End) passed_test_cases ,
Sum(Case When Status = 'OK' Then test_value End) total_value  
From Test_Cases Full Outer Join Test_Groups On Name = Group_Name
Group By Group_Name,Name
order by Name_Of_The_Group;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
select t.name,
       count(c.*)as total,
       sum(case when c.status='OK'then 1 else 0 end) as passed,
Case when sum(case when c.status='OK'then test_value end)Is NULL then 0
     Else sum(case when c.status='OK'then test_value end)End as total_value
from test_groups t
left join test_cases c on t.name=c.group_name
group by t.name
order by total_value desc,t.name;
```

Comment: Hello, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help Thanks!